How to access my github token with my flutter app?
I want to build a flutter app with github services. and I want when the user logged in I save his token in my local storage, so I can use APIs that requires a token.
is it possible if I use an OAuth github app and appwrite ?
I search for github login process and it was about how to login with your github account and it will take you to your main account page on github.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
